# CE 2.2.1 migration fails with "Killed" on MAP STEP at 53%

Tags: magento2.2

Migrating 1.9.3.3 CE to 2.2.1 CE : Migration fails 53% with the message "KILLED". No information in the migration.log that I can find that's helpful. memory_limit = -1.. out of ideas.

```
[2017-11-11 03:28:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
53% [==============>-------------] Remaining Time: 1 secKilled
```

Comment: Old question, but for what it's worth, I'm getting this on the SalesOrder step, and it looks like that while I also have memory_limit = -1, it's just running out of memory in the virtual machine I'm running it on. Try running `dmesg` and seeing if you see "Out of memory" issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Swap memory 。

```
# /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=16384
# /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
# /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```